# unable to add refrence of restful wcf service in windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, windows-services, wcf-rest

When i tried to add the reference of restful wcf service to windows service. I am getting "The type or namespace name 'RestfulService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" error.

**MY Interface Is**

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "RJContract",
     Namespace = "RestfulService",
     SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/rjdata/{name}")]
        string RJData(string name);
    }
```

**App.Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestfulService.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/RestfulService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint  binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestfulService.IService1" bindingConfiguration="RESTBindingConfiguration"
                   behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior"/>

      </service>
    </services>



    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RESTBindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

    </bindings>



    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But i am able to add the reference with the following.

```
 [ServiceContract(Name = "RJContract",
         Namespace = "RestfulService",
         SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
        public interface IService1
        {
            [OperationContract]
            string RJData(string name);
        }
```

**In windows Hosting**

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ServiceHost sHost;
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RestfulService.Service1));
                sHost.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
```

where RestfulService is my reference to the wcf service

Comment: By add service reference, do you mean you're trying to add the service through the Add Service Reference of Visual Studio?  If so, then you can't do that for RESTful services; you don't use a proxy to communicate with RESTful services, you make the call directly over HTTP using an HTTP API.

Comment: you can't. need to consume your service using some server/client side api, which can do http get/post, can use jquery ajax if ok to call from client/Javascript side, else use HttpWebRequest if need to consume service at C# side.

Comment: @Tim:- I am adding the project as reference

Comment: @LearningNeverEnds:- I am going to consume it in the client using javascript. But first i want to host it in the windows service

Comment: @Gangadhar - how it's hosted (IIS, Windows Service, self-hosted) is irrelevant in terms of how you access it.  If you want to host it in Windows service, you need to write the logic to host the service - you don't reference the service to host it.

Comment: @Gangadhar like Tim told, you need to host it yourself as your win service app is responsible and so provide hosting itself, can follow this: http://debugmode.net/2010/06/01/restselfhosted/

Comment: I have added my hosting code also please see the edit

Comment: What is the namespace for your service contract (in the code)?  The namespace value that you set in the `ServiceContract` attribute is for the service and has nothing to do with the namespace for the assembly.  I.e., what do you have for `namespace` at the start of your code?

Comment: Also, what type of project is your service?  Library, application, ...?  Is it a separate project from your Windows Service?

Comment: @Tim:- its WCF Service Library and it is separate project

Comment: Then did you refer that library in your win service, if not refer it.

Comment: @Gangadhar - Is the namespace of the WCF Service Library `ResftfulService`?

Comment: @Tim:- yes it is RestfulService

Comment: are you getting build error at this? line `sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RestfulService.Service1));`

Comment: @LearningNeverEnds:- yes

Comment: @LearningNeverEnds:- You are correct i am getting error in that line. the error is "The type or namespace name 'RestfulService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Then for sure win service is unable to locate the RestfulService namespace, which you mentioned is in your wcf service library, so please follow steps mentioned by Tim in his answer below, and it should fix it. If still nothing is working, then try changing your service library namespace to something else, rebuild, and then get reference added to win service project, clean and rebuild your win service project, and see if that helps. also refer new namespace of library project in your win service code in place of RestfulService.

Comment: @LearningNeverEnds:- I tried all the thing that you told but no luck

Comment: just a blind/wild guess, but do you have your windows service project and service library project in different configuration, i mean one in debug mode and other one is in release, can u plz check on to make sure they both and any other project in your solution are all in same mode either debug or release? then clean entire solution and rebuild. I am not very sure but as you told even after Mine/Tim's suggestions it's same issue, so i can just guess that  it's some issue with projects not knowing or able to get referred in right way or at right place or in required namespace,you want them at.

Comment: @Gangadhar did you get this resolved yet?

Answer (score 1):

To add and use the reference to your service library, you need to add a reference to the service library assembly in your Windows Service project, and then add the `using RestfulService` statement to the using directives in your Windows Service code.

Also, since you're wanting to use REST, I'd recommend using [WebServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.aspx) instead of `ServiceHost`:

```
using RestfulService;

public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    WebServiceHost sHost;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            sHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(RestfulService.Service1));
            sHost.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        sHost.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing yourself by overlapping standards of SOAP and REST.

RESTful style of services do not follow SOAP standards. The Add Reference feature in VS downloads the metadata (including WSDL) of a SOAP based service to know about its contracts/bindings/etc. However, in case of a REST based service these standards/mechanisms do not hold true and a formal metadata may not be published for a consumer to discover and generate proxies.

For calling a REST service you'd need to manually create a proxy that reaches the service. You can use classes like [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) for same.

Answer (score -1):

By default rest services(webhttp bindings) are not supported in adding references.
If you want to add the reference you can add one soap endpoint and then try to add the reference. Then it will work.

if you want to make a call to restful service then you can do like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.1.118/PracticeWcfService1/Service1.svc/RestTypeWithSecure/GetProductData");
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
                WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();
        string text;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

        Response.write(text );
}
```